How to extract values from a multi level XML and make them a new format
I've tried several posts but no success yet, I would like to change the format of the following tables (the levels keep going up to 100)

        <level val="1">
            <hp>94</hp>
            <mp>30</mp>
            <cp>37.6</cp>
            <hpRegen>2</hpRegen>
            <mpRegen>0.9</mpRegen>
            <cpRegen>2</cpRegen>
        </level>
        <level val="2">
            <hp>107.65</hp>
            <mp>35.46</mp>
            <cp>43.06</cp>
            <hpRegen>2</hpRegen>
            <mpRegen>0.9</mpRegen>
            <cpRegen>2</cpRegen>
        </level>
        <level val="3">
            <hp>121.45</hp>
            <mp>40.98</mp>
            <cp>48.58</cp>
            <hpRegen>3</hpRegen>
            <mpRegen>0.9</mpRegen>
            <cpRegen>2</cpRegen>
        </level>

and transform that to the following format (divided each level by semicolon):
        <set hpTable="94;107.65;121.45"/>
        <set mpTable="30;35.46;40.98"/>
        <set cpTable="37.6;43.06;48.58"/>
        <set hpRegenTable="2;2;3"/>
        <set mpRegenTable="0.9;0.9;0.9"/>
        <set cpRegenTable="2;2;2"/>


Thanks in advance.
Tried manual removing tags and transform, several python etree replace but most ended up in errors

XSLT is a technology made for such tasks

In XSLT 2.0 or later:
<xsl:for-each-group select="//level/*" group-by="name()">
  <set>
     <xsl:attribute name="{current-grouping-key()}Table"
                    select="string-join(current-group(), ';')"/>
  </set>
</xsl:for-each-group>

